# How can I disable persistence undo in Vim 7.3?

Tags: vim

How can I disable persistence undo in Vim 7.3?

I found that sometime, after doing some code modification, I want to go back to the state that i just open that file. But if have such persistence undo option, when i pressing `u` , it will undo more than i want.

Comment: Pressing U should step back through the edit tree. like ctrl and z in word.
I'm not sure I understand, if you press U is it doing too much in which case are you sure you have the undo buffer active?

Comment: the persistence undo will also save my edit history after i close the file. so when i reopen the file again, when i press U, it can undo my previous change I close the file. that is not i want :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Persistent undo is an opt-in feature. If you don't want it simply remove the related settings from your `~/.vimrc`.

Removing `set undofile` and manually deleting the undo files should be enough.

See `:help persistent-undo`.

Comment: Note that the vimrc_example.vim includes `set undofile` by default now. So user who source vimrc_example.vim in their own .vimrc may be getting this option without intending to.

Answer (score 6):

A solution without disabling persistent undo would be the [`:earlier 1f`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#:earlier) command. This rewinds the undo history to where it was the last time the file was saved. (You can keep executing it to go to each previous save spot, or supply a number other than 1 to skip several saves.)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this simple solution:

Append `set noundofile` to `$HOME/.vimrc` file (if the file doesn't exist, create it).

Alternatively, as suggested by romainl, you can also find the `set undofile` line in you vim configuration files and remove it. There are at least three configuration files for vim:

- system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
- user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
- 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"